# can I upload multiple files with Google apps script?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, web-applications, google-apps-script

I am trying to upload files to Google Drive using Google Apps script that also deployed as web app.

In the .html file I got -

```
<form id="myForm" action='#' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
           google.script.run.uploadFiles(this.parentNode)" id="upload-button">
```

In the .gs file I got -

```
function uploadFiles(form) {
var file = form['filesToUpload[]'];
```

I have deployed web app with this code(not only this code of-course).

Each time i upload more then one file in the web app, the variable - 'file' contain only the first file i had uploaded. and not all the files.
In other words the fileUpload objects contain each time I have tried the fileUpload-dictionary contain only one file.

fileUpload class - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/file-upload

I read a lot of documentation and I begun to think that it's impossible to upload multiple files using Google apps script(while choosing multiple files in one input of course).

Anyone knows something about it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few things, and I agree that it's impossible. There is a deprecated API method [getAllBlobs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAllBlobs%28%29), but even that returns a single-element array with just the first file, even when I select multiple files.

On the client-side, the sandbox mode (in which the script runs) seems to prevent [fileInput.files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) property from working: it's always undefined.

Together with a complete lack of documentation on this, it makes for a convincing conclusion that as of May 2015, Google Scripts does not allow multiple file uploads.